# Why is BrowserRouter and Route from 'react-router-dom' not working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

These are the contents of the project directory named `my-app`.

```
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
public
└── index.html
src
├── App.js
├── index.js
└── pages
    └── Home.js
```

`public/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <!-- all the components are displayed in this #root element -->
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`src/App.js`

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';

function App() {
        return <>
                <BrowserRouter>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
                </BrowserRouter>
        </>;
}
export default App;
```

`src/index.js`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`src/pages/Home.js`

```
function Home() {
        return <h1>Homepage</h1>
}
export default Home;
```

When I run `npm start` in the `my-app` directory, the project compiles with the following message :

```sh
Compiled successfully!

You can now view my-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://<network_ip>:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

asset static/js/bundle.js 1.49 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset index.html 334 bytes [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 190 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 1.39 MiB (javascript) 28.1 KiB (runtime) [cached] 109 modules
webpack 5.66.0 compiled successfully in 1509 ms
```

When I open http://localhost:3000 on a web browser though, I get a blank page, which means that no JSX / HTML is rendered into the #root div at `public/index.html`. This only happens when I introduce the lines with `BrowserRouter` and `Router` tags.
Is someone else able to reproduce this error? I can't figure out what's wrong with this!

Edit : Here are the versions of node, npx and npm that I'm using.

```
:~$ node -v
v16.13.2
:~$ npm -v
8.1.2
:~$ npx -v
8.1.2
```

Comment: What version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: ```
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
```

Comment: Its the version of react-router that matters here.

Answer (score 2):

Since `react-router-dom` v6, some props changed for components that it exposes such as `Route`, and `Switch` is replaced by `Routes`:

Here is your code modified to match with new changes:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Also, no need for `<>` (aka `React.Fragment` since `BrowserRouter` is the only item present in jsx.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now! Guess I need to check the latest documentation before every single line of code. Updates in react packages are getting insane.

Comment: Also, i think `<BrowserRouter>` can be the root element of the returning JSX code. I think fragments `<>` can be omitted.

Comment: Yep, that is the skill we all need to be efficient. Although this kind of dependency upgrade is not that common. These are breaking changes, but don't require much rewrite

Comment: @nikostav96 true, thanks. I added it to the answer.